# Alternatives to least square, overestimate?

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression, weighted-least-squares

Ok so I have a very simple linear system of equations with three unknowns and eight equations. Is there anyone that can tell me if there is a method or some way to find a solution which overestimates or gives a solution with high values for my three unknowns?

I have tried the least square method but it gives me close to average values and I need a solution that is weighted more towards the higher values but that still works.

Comment: You don't normally use least-squares in an over-determined system like you have. Are you sure it isn't three equations and eight unknowns?

Comment: Yes positive, what would you use to solve such a system then??

It's basically three products that all draw electrical power and a total consumption number for them so every row is for example 2x + 3y + 4z = 1500 and I need a high estimation of x,y and z as to not underestimate the total power consumption.